# 52-card poker deck question

Tags: probability

A 52-card poker deck is randomly divided into two equal parts. What is the probability that the resulting halves each contain exactly 13 red cards?

Approach: 52C26* 26C13 divided by 52C5

Comment: where did 52C5 come from?

Comment: 5 cards per hand

Comment: that isn't relevant to the problem asked, though

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$= the number of red cards picked of 26 selections. Then $X$ has a hyper geometric distribution and we can say 
$$ P(X=k)=\dfrac{{26 \choose k} {26\choose{26-k}}}{52\choose 26} $$
Now note that the probability that each half has 13 reds is the same as the probbility of choosing exactly 13 reds out of 26 choices. So the answer to the question is just $P(X=13)$.